# Save a Javascript object into a NoSQL database and retrieve it afterwards

Tags: javascript, database, nosql, neo4j

I have an Javascript object that I want to save in a NoSQL database (Neo4j).

Is there a way to save this object in the database to retrieve it later on and have it acting like it was never sent to and retrieve from database, that means having all the members (properties and methods) that were defined?

If so, how would you do that?

Comment: Two acronyms: [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966388/storing-js-arrays-and-objects-in-a-database

Comment: @jared. But JSON isn't really a real object. Also you can't save methods with JSON.

Comment: I dont think js objects can be serializable.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "real object", if you can explain that, it would be helpful. Also, your original question did not mention methods. Is there some reason you can't use client-side code to load an object described in JSON into a first-class object with methods?

Comment: @Mithun: Unfortunately that one doesn't explain how to store methods. But perhaps I don't wanna store methods in a database.

Comment: @Jared. That is because the implementation is not done by me so I can not recreate the object with a object literal. I'll try if I can do that somehow.

Comment: I suspect that what you're trying to do is save a users state and then recreate it at some later point exactly as they left it. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jared: That is correct. I have a user object that I create for each user. The thing is that each of these users are statecharts so I need a memory for them so they a user will always continue in the same state where he left off. Saving the methods in a db seems to be a very bad idea and also consume a lot of disk space. Maybe there is a way to just save the properties and recreate them together with the methods from the frontend when I wanna "resume" the object.

Comment: I think your best bet is to find a way, on "unload" or something (maybe a "draft save"), to characterize the charts into properties and then reinflate the charts on request. Saving the client browser's in-memory Javascript native objects, however, is not really feasible AFAIK.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5542/discussion-between-ajsie-and-jared-farrish)

Comment: Saving things in a neo4j database which are not directly related to the essence of the graph is in general a bad idea, mainly because the database is likely to grow too large. Save the JSON objects somewhere else like a document-oriented NoSQL DB and point to them with a property on a neo4j node or relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend writing a server side API for handling your basic CRUD operations on Neo4j. You shouldn't publicly expose your Neo4j REST API as it can lead to security vulnerabilities down the line. If someone knows you're running Neo4j, they can target your database directly if you expose Neo4j's native REST API. If you have a layer of abstraction between your database and the public, it will generally be safer.